# .prop() vs .attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, attr, prop

So [jQuery 1.6](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.6/) has the new function [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

```
$(selector).click(function(){
    //instead of:
    this.getAttribute('style');
    //do i use:
    $(this).prop('style');
    //or:
    $(this).attr('style');
})
```

or in this case do they do the same thing?

And if I *do* have to switch to using `prop()`, all the old `attr()` calls will break if i switch to 1.6?

**UPDATE**

```js
selector = '#id'

$(selector).click(function() {
    //instead of:
    var getAtt = this.getAttribute('style');
    //do i use:
    var thisProp = $(this).prop('style');
    //or:
    var thisAttr = $(this).attr('style');

    console.log(getAtt, thisProp, thisAttr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='id' style="color: red;background: orange;">test</div>
```

(see also this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/JpUF2/)

The console logs the `getAttribute` as a string, and the `attr` as a string, but the `prop` as a `CSSStyleDeclaration`, Why? And how does that affect my coding in the future?

Comment: This will be of definite interest: http://books.google.ca/books?id=2weL0iAfrEMC&pg=PT334&lpg=PT334&dq=html+attributes+vs+dom+properties&source=bl&ots=_9VAqAT03C&sig=C8llDHg4KHT7GjgSfqVqNMa8eqo&hl=en&ei=SFnATY47hezSAajPyJwF&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=9&ved=0CFkQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=html%20attributes%20vs%20dom%20properties&f=false

Comment: @Neal, it's because this change transcends jQuery. The difference between HTML attributes and DOM properties is massive.

Comment: @Matt but what was `attr` returning before 1.6? wasnt it always returning a string?

Comment: .attr() has changed dramatically in jQuery 1.6. Here the problem is explained:

http://edgarinvillegas.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/upgrading-to-jquery-1-6-troubleshooting/

Comment: @Edgar, alot of the problems were fixed in [jQuery 1.6.1](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/10/jquery-1-6-1-rc-1-released/)

Comment: It makes me sad to see jQuery's reverted the changes. They're heading in the wrong direction.

Comment: @Neal. Yes, and it just complicates the problem further instead of separating the two methods.

Comment: AFAIK as of 1.9 `attr()` won't do "magic" for properties anymore. So `.attr('checked', false)` will not do what one might expect.

Comment: @Neal - the access to properties via attr() has been removed for some things starting with 1.9.0 jQuery http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/ scroll down and read .attr() versus .prop()   boolean attributes such as checked and disabled on a checkbox are affected by this change

Comment: see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h682v/4/, change it to 1.9.1 version, and see the properties for disabled are not changed using attr - check/uncheck of those two at the bottom are still accessible until you change the `attr()` stuff to `prop()` - one instance of the change.

Comment: Your collective knowledge of jQuery is impressive. However when someone says x vs y they just want a simple comparison, when to use one and not the other. They're not after a deep dive. That's why they're here not reading the documentation. All terrible answers

Comment: @BritishDeveloper the answer is more complicated than simply stating always use x or y because it depends on what you intend to get. Do you want the attribute, or do you want the property? they are two very different things.

Comment: see also [Properties and Attributes in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6003819/1048572)

Comment: You don't need `$(el).prop(...)` any more. See: https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#get_outer_html

Answer (score 1967, accepted):

**Update 1 November 2012**

My original answer applies specifically to jQuery 1.6. My advice remains the same but jQuery 1.6.1 changed things slightly: in the face of the predicted pile of broken websites, the jQuery team [reverted `attr()` to something close to (but not exactly the same as) its old behaviour for Boolean attributes](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/). John Resig also [blogged about it](http://ejohn.org/blog/jquery-16-and-attr/). I can see the difficulty they were in but still disagree with his recommendation to prefer `attr()`.

**Original answer**

If you've only ever used jQuery and not the DOM directly, this could be a confusing change, although it is definitely an improvement conceptually. Not so good for the bazillions of sites using jQuery that will break as a result of this change though.

I'll summarize the main issues:

- You usually want `prop()` rather than `attr()`.
- In the majority of cases, `prop()` does what `attr()` used to do. Replacing calls to `attr()` with `prop()` in your code will generally work.
- Properties are generally simpler to deal with than attributes. An attribute value may only be a string whereas a property can be of any type. For example, the `checked` property is a Boolean, the `style` property is an object with individual properties for each style, the `size` property is a number.
- Where both a property and an attribute with the same name exists, usually updating one will update the other, but this is not the case for certain attributes of inputs, such as `value` and `checked`: for these attributes, the property always represents the current state while the attribute (except in old versions of IE) corresponds to the default value/checkedness of the input (reflected in the `defaultValue` / `defaultChecked` property).
- This change removes some of the layer of magic jQuery stuck in front of attributes and properties, meaning jQuery developers will have to learn a bit about the difference between properties and attributes. This is a good thing.

If you're a jQuery developer and are confused by this whole business about properties and attributes, you need to take a step back and learn a little about it, since jQuery is no longer trying so hard to shield you from this stuff. For the authoritative but somewhat dry word on the subject, there's the specs: [DOM4](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/), [HTML DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/), [DOM Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core), [DOM Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/). Mozilla's DOM documentation is valid for most modern browsers and is easier to read than the specs, so you may find their [DOM reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/gecko_dom_reference) helpful. There's a [section on element properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element#Properties).

As an example of how properties are simpler to deal with than attributes, consider a checkbox that is initially checked. Here are two possible pieces of valid HTML to do this:

```html
<input id="cb" type="checkbox" checked>
<input id="cb" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
```

So, how do you find out if the checkbox is checked with jQuery? Look on Stack Overflow and you'll commonly find the following suggestions:

- `if ( $("#cb").attr("checked") === true ) {...}`
- `if ( $("#cb").attr("checked") == "checked" ) {...}`
- `if ( $("#cb").is(":checked") ) {...}`

This is actually the simplest thing in the world to do with the `checked` Boolean property, which has existed and worked flawlessly in every major scriptable browser since 1995:

`if (document.getElementById("cb").checked) {...}`

The property also makes checking or unchecking the checkbox trivial:

`document.getElementById("cb").checked = false`

In jQuery 1.6, this unambiguously becomes

`$("#cb").prop("checked", false)`

The idea of using the `checked` attribute for scripting a checkbox is unhelpful and unnecessary. The property is what you need.

- It's not obvious what the correct way to check or uncheck the checkbox is using the `checked` attribute
- The attribute value reflects the default rather than the current visible state (except in some older versions of IE, thus making things still harder). The attribute tells you nothing about the whether the checkbox on the page is checked. See http://jsfiddle.net/VktA6/49/.

Comment: @Neal: A DOM element is an object. Properties are properties of that object, just like any other programming object. Some of those props  get their initial values from the attributes in the markup, which are also stored on the DOM object in a *separate* map of attributes. In most cases, writing to a prop only changes the prop, although sadly there are some props that write any changes through to the underlying attr (`value` for instance), but let's try to mostly ignore that. 99% of the time, you want to work with props. If you need to work with an actual attribute, you'll probably know that.

Answer (score 698):

I think [Tim said it quite well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr/5876747#5876747), but let's step back:

A DOM element is an object, a thing in memory. Like most objects in OOP, it has *properties*. It also, separately, has a map of the attributes defined on the element (usually coming from the markup that the browser read to create the element). Some of the element's *properties* get their *initial* values from *attributes* with the same or similar names (`value` gets its initial value from the "value" attribute; `href` gets its initial value from the "href" attribute, but it's not exactly the same value; `className` from the "class" attribute). Other properties get their initial values in other ways: For instance, the `parentNode` property gets its value based on what its parent element is; an element always has a `style` property, whether it has a "style" attribute or not.

Let's consider this anchor in a page at `http://example.com/testing.html`:

```html
<a href="foo.html" class="test one" name="fooAnchor" id="fooAnchor">Hi</a>
```

Some gratuitous ASCII art (and leaving out a lot of stuff):

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
|              HTMLAnchorElement             |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| href:        "http://example.com/foo.html" |
| name:        "fooAnchor"                   |
| id:          "fooAnchor"                   |
| className:   "test one"                    |
| attributes:  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
|              | href:  "foo.html"        |  |
|              | name:  "fooAnchor"       |  |
|              | id:    "fooAnchor"       |  |
|              | class: "test one"        |  |
|              +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Note that the properties and attributes are distinct.

Now, although they are distinct, because all of this evolved rather than being designed from the ground up, a number of properties write back to the attribute they derived from if you set them. But not all do, and as you can see from `href` above, the mapping is not always a straight "pass the value on", sometimes there's interpretation involved.

When I talk about properties being properties of an object, I'm not speaking in the abstract. Here's some non-jQuery code:

```js
const link = document.getElementById("fooAnchor");
console.log(link.href);                 // Shows "http://example.com/foo.html"
console.log(link.getAttribute("href")); // Shows "foo.html"
```

The `link` object is a real thing, and you can see there's a real distinction between accessing a *property* on it, and accessing an *attribute*.

As Tim said, the **vast majority** of the time, we want to be working with properties. Partially that's because their values (even their names) tend to be more consistent across browsers. We mostly only want to work with attributes when there is no property related to it (custom attributes), or when we know that for that particular attribute, the attribute and the property are not 1:1 (as with `href` and "href" above).

The standard properties are laid out in the various DOM specs:

- [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/) *(largely obsolete, see the [HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) instead)*
- [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/) *(obsolete)*
- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/) *(obsolete)*
- [DOM4](https://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/)

These specs have excellent indexes and I recommend keeping links to them handy; I use them all the time.

Custom attributes would include, for instance, any `data-xyz` attributes you might put on elements to provide meta-data to your code (now that that's valid as of HTML5, as long as you stick to the `data-` prefix). (Recent versions of jQuery give you access to `data-xyz` elements via the `data` function, but that function is **not** just an accessor for `data-xyz` attributes [it does both more and less than that]; unless you actually need its features, I'd use the `attr` function to interact with `data-xyz` attribute.)

The `attr` function used to have some convoluted logic around getting what they thought you wanted, rather than literally getting the attribute. It conflated the concepts. Moving to `prop` and `attr` was meant to de-conflate them. Briefly in v1.6.0 jQuery went too far in that regard, but functionality [was quickly added back](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/10/jquery-1-6-1-rc-1-released/) to `attr` to handle the common situations where people use `attr` when technically they should use `prop`.

Answer (score 259):

This change has been a long time coming for jQuery. For years, they've been content with a function named `attr()` that mostly retrieved DOM properties, not the result you'd expect from the name. The segregation of [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) and [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) should help alleviate some of the confusion between HTML attributes and DOM properties. `$.fn.prop()` grabs the specified DOM property, while `$.fn.attr()` grabs the specified HTML attribute.

To fully understand how they work, here's an extended explanation on the difference between HTML attributes and DOM properties.:

### HTML Attributes

#### Syntax:

`<body onload="foo()">`

**Purpose:**
Allows markup to have data associated with it for events, rendering, and other purposes.

**Visualization:**
[image: HTML Attributes]
The class attribute is shown here on the body. It's accessible through the following code:

```
var attr;
attr = document.body.getAttribute("class");
//IE 8 Quirks and below
attr = document.body.getAttribute("className");
```

Attributes are returned in string form and can be inconsistent from browser to browser. However, they can be vital in some situations. As exemplified above, IE 8 Quirks Mode (and below) expects the name of a DOM property in get/set/removeAttribute instead of the attribute name. This is one of many reasons why it's important to know the difference.

### DOM Properties

#### Syntax:

`document.body.onload = foo;`

**Purpose:**
Gives access to properties that belong to element nodes. These properties are similar to attributes, but are only accessible through JavaScript. This is an important difference that helps clarify the role of DOM properties. **Please note that attributes are completely different from properties**, as this event handler assignment is useless and won't receive the event (body doesn't have an onload event, only an onload attribute).

**Visualization:**
[image: DOM Properties]

Here, you'll notice a list of properties under the "DOM" tab in Firebug. These are DOM properties. You'll immediately notice quite a few of them, as you'll have used them before without knowing it. Their values are what you'll be receiving through JavaScript.

### Documentation

- [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide by
  David Flanagan](http://books.google.ca/books?id=2weL0iAfrEMC&lpg=PT334&ots=_9VAqAT03C&dq=html%20attributes%20vs%20dom%20properties&pg=PT332#v=onepage&q&f=false)
- [HTML Attributes,
  Mozilla Dev Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Attributes)
- [DOM Element Properties, Mozilla Dev Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element#Properties)

### Example

HTML: `<textarea id="test" value="foo"></textarea>`

JavaScript: `alert($('#test').attr('value'));`

In earlier versions of jQuery, this returns an empty string. In 1.6, it returns the proper value, `foo`.

Without having glanced at the new code for either function, I can say with confidence that the confusion has more to do with the difference between HTML attributes and DOM properties, than with the code itself. Hopefully, this cleared some things up for you.

-Matt

Comment: `$.prop()` gets DOM properties, `$.attr()` gets HTML attributes. I'm trying to bridge the gap psychologically so you can understand the difference between the two.

Comment: Boy, I am confused now too.  So `$('#test').prop('value')` does not return anything?  Nor does `.attr('checked')` for a checkbox?  But it used to?  Now you'd have to change it to `prop('checked')`?  I don't understand the need for this distinction - why is it important to differentiate between HTML attributes and DOM properties?  What is the common use-case that made this change *"a long time coming"*?  What is *wrong* with abstracting the distinction between the two away, since it seems like their use-cases mostly overlap?

Comment: why differentiate between HTML attributes and DOM properties? When you load a webpage in the browser HTML is parsed into DOM, which is used for the visual presentation. Say you have a form with a checkbox not checked, and you check it. If you use $.attr() it is not checked which is correct from the HTML. However the $.prop() will be checked, which is also correct as we checked it. If you need to work with the source code, or as other pointed out initial value, use $.attr() else use $.prop(). Also, in Chrome Developer Tools the elements are showing DOM as html not HTML SOURCE.

Answer (score 255):

A property is in the DOM; an attribute is in the HTML that is parsed into the DOM.

#### Further detail

If you change an attribute, the change will be reflected in the DOM (sometimes with a different name).

Example: Changing the `class` attribute of a tag will change the `className` property of that tag in the DOM (That's because `class` is a reserved word in JavaScript and can't be used for a property name).
If you have no attribute on a tag, you still have the corresponding DOM property with an empty or a default value.

Example: While your tag has no `class` attribute, the DOM property `className` does exist with a empty string value.

**edit**

If you change the one, the other will be changed by a controller, and vice versa.
This controller is not in jQuery, but in the browser's native code.

Answer (score 146):

It's just the distinction between HTML attributes and DOM objects that causes a confusion. For those that are comfortable acting on the DOM elements native properties such a `this.src` `this.value` `this.checked` etc, `.prop` is a very warm welcome to the family. For others, it's just an added layer of confusion. Let's clear that up.

The easiest way to see the difference between `.attr` and `.prop` is the following example:

```
<input blah="hello">
```

1. **`$('input').attr('blah')`**: returns `'hello'` as expected. No suprises here.
2. **`$('input').prop('blah')`**: returns `undefined` -- because it's trying to do `[HTMLInputElement].blah` -- and no such property on that DOM object exists. It only exists in the scope as an attribute of that element i.e. `[HTMLInputElement].getAttribute('blah')`

Now we change a few things like so:

```
$('input').attr('blah', 'apple');
$('input').prop('blah', 'pear');
```

1. **`$('input').attr('blah')`**: returns `'apple'` eh? Why not "pear" as this was set last on that element. Because the property was changed on the input attribute, not the DOM input element itself -- they basically almost work independently of each other.
2. **`$('input').prop('blah')`**: returns `'pear'`

The thing you really need to be careful with is just **do not mix the usage of these for the same property throughout your application** for the above reason.

**See a fiddle demonstrating the difference:** http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/uLQXc/

---

### `.attr` vs `.prop`:

#### Round 1: style

```
<input style="font:arial;"/>
```

- `.attr('style')` -- returns inline styles for the matched element i.e. `"font:arial;"`
- `.prop('style')` -- returns an style declaration object i.e. `CSSStyleDeclaration`

#### Round 2: value

```
<input value="hello" type="text"/>   

$('input').prop('value', 'i changed the value');
```

- `.attr('value')` -- returns `'hello'` *
- `.prop('value')` -- returns `'i changed the value'`

* Note: jQuery for this reason has a `.val()` method, which internally is equivalent to `.prop('value')`

Answer (score 61):

**TL;DR**

Use `prop()` over `attr()` in the majority of cases.

A *property* is the current state of the input element. An *attribute* is the default value.

A property can contain things of different types. An attribute can only contain strings

Comment: if possible to come with few easy sample of what u r saying and also show when to use `prop() and when to go for attr()`. waiting for answer :)

Answer (score 42):

**Dirty checkedness**

This concept provides an example where the difference is observable: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-input-checked-dirty

Try it out:

- click the button. Both checkboxes got checked.
- uncheck both checkboxes.
- click the button again. Only the `prop` checkbox got checked. BANG!

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#attr').attr('checked', 'checked')
  $('#prop').prop('checked', true)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>attr <input id="attr" type="checkbox"></label>
<label>prop <input id="prop" type="checkbox"></label>
<button type="button">Set checked attr and prop.</button>
```

For some attributes  like `disabled` on `button`, adding or removing the content attribute `disabled="disabled"` always toggles the property (called IDL attribute in HTML5) because http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fe-disabled says:

> The disabled IDL attribute must reflect the disabled content attribute.

so you might get away with it, although it is ugly since it modifies HTML without need.

For other attributes like `checked="checked"` on `input type="checkbox"`, things break, because once you click on it, it becomes dirty, and then adding or removing the `checked="checked"` content attribute **does not toggle checkedness anymore**.

This is why you should use mostly `.prop`, as it affects the effective property directly, instead of relying on complex side-effects of modifying the HTML.

Answer (score 38):

All is in [the doc](https://api.jquery.com/prop/):

> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.

So use prop!

Answer (score 34):

**attributes** are in your HTML *text document/file* (== imagine this is the result of your html markup parsed), whereas
**properties** are in HTML *DOM tree* (== basically an actual property of some object in JS sense).

Importantly, many of them are synced (if you update `class` property, `class` attribute in html will also be updated; and otherwise). **But** some attributes may be synced to unexpected properties - eg, **attribute** `checked` corresponds to **property** `defaultChecked`, so that

- manually checking a checkbox will change `.prop('checked')` value, but will not change `.attr('checked')` and `.prop('defaultChecked')` values
- setting `$('#input').prop('defaultChecked', true)` will also change `.attr('checked')`, but this will not be visible on an element.

> **Rule of thumb is**: `.prop()` method should be used for boolean attributes/properties and for properties which do not exist in html
>   (such as window.location). All other attributes (ones you can see in
>   the html) can and should continue to be manipulated with the `.attr()`
>   method. (http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/10/jquery-1-6-1-rc-1-released/)

And here is a table that shows where `.prop()` is preferred (even though `.attr()` can still be used).

### [image: table with preferred usage]

---

#### Why would you sometimes want to use .prop() instead of .attr() where latter is officially adviced?

1. `.prop()` can return any type - string, integer, boolean; while `.attr()` always returns a string.
2. `.prop()` is said to be about 2.5 times faster than `.attr()`.

Answer (score 29):

`.attr()`:

- Get the value of an **attribute** for the first element in the set of matched elements.
- Gives you the value of element as it was defined in the html on page load

`.prop()`:

- Get the value of a **property** for the first element in the set of matched elements.
- Gives the updated values of elements which is modified via javascript/jquery

Answer (score 14):

Usually you'll want to use properties.
Use attributes only for:

1. Getting a custom HTML attribute (since it's not synced with a DOM property).
2. Getting a HTML attribute that doesn't sync with a DOM property, e.g. get the "original value" of a standard HTML attribute, like `<input value="abc">.`

Answer (score 9):

`attributes` -> HTML

`properties` -> DOM

Comment: I know what you want to say, but HTML is a markup language, and the DOM a representation created out of the HTML. A DOMElement has both _attributes_ and _properties_.

Answer (score 7):

Before jQuery 1.6 , the `attr()` method ***sometimes*** took property values into account when retrieving attributes, this caused rather inconsistent behavior.

The introduction of the `prop()` method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while `.attr()` retrieves attributes.

The Docs:

`jQuery.attr()`
Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements.

`jQuery.prop()`
Get the value of a property for the first element in the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 6):

### One thing `.attr()` can do that `.prop()` can't:  affect CSS selectors

Here's an issue I didn't see in the other answers.

CSS selector `[name=value]`

- will respond to `.attr('name', 'value')`
- but not always to `.prop('name', 'value')`

`.prop()` affects only a few attribute-selectors

- [`input[name]`](https://jsfiddle.net/51xosq29/)  (thanks [@TimDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr/5876747?noredirect=1#comment99696762_5876747))

`.attr()` affects all attribute-selectors

- [`input[value]`](https://jsfiddle.net/BobStein/cqfwtyj9/2/)
- [`input[naame]`](https://jsfiddle.net/BobStein/tw038Laf/2/)
- [`span[name]`](https://jsfiddle.net/BobStein/m2hsxder/2/)
- [`input[data-custom-attribute]`](https://jsfiddle.net/BobStein/szto3d06/3/) (neither will `.data('custom-attribute')` affect this selector)

Comment: Finally, someone is talking about setting attributes and their values with `attr` and `prop`. Everyone is talking about the `get` usage of those two methods and I can't find what I'm looking for. Thank you for adding this.

Answer (score 3):

Gently reminder about using `prop()`, example:

```
if ($("#checkbox1").prop('checked')) {
    isDelete = 1;
} else {
    isDelete = 0;
}
```

The function above is used to check if checkbox1 is checked or not, if checked: return 1; if not: return 0. Function prop() used here as a GET function.

```
if ($("#checkbox1").prop('checked', true)) {
    isDelete = 1;
} else {
    isDelete = 0;
}
```

The function above is used to set checkbox1 to be checked and ALWAYS return 1. Now function prop() used as a SET function.

**Don't mess up.**

P/S: When I'm checking Image ***src*** property. If the ***src*** is empty, **prop** return the current URL of the page (wrong), and **attr** return empty string (right).

Answer (score 1):

There are few more considerations in prop() vs attr():

- selectedIndex, tagName, nodeName, nodeType, ownerDocument, defaultChecked, and defaultSelected..etc should be retrieved and set with the .prop() method. These do not have corresponding attributes and are only properties.
- For input type checkbox

  ```
     .attr('checked') //returns  checked
     .prop('checked') //returns  true
     .is(':checked') //returns true
  ```
- prop method returns Boolean value for checked, selected, disabled,
  readOnly..etc while attr returns defined string. So, you can directly
  use .prop(‘checked’) in if condition.
- .attr() calls .prop() internally so .attr() method will be slightly
  slower than accessing them directly through .prop().

Comment: I am 49% sure that the attr method does _not_ call prop internally

Answer (score 0):

> 1) A property is in the DOM; an attribute is in the HTML that is
>   parsed into the DOM.
>
> 2) $( elem ).attr( "checked" ) (1.6.1+)   "checked" (String) Will
>   change with checkbox state
>
> 3) $( elem ).attr( "checked" ) (pre-1.6)    true (Boolean) Changed
>   with checkbox state

- Mostly we want to use for DOM object rather then custom attribute
  like `data-img, data-xyz`.
- Also some of difference when accessing `checkbox` value and `href`
  with `attr()` and `prop()` as thing change with DOM output with
  `prop()` as full link from `origin` and `Boolean` value for checkbox
  `(pre-1.6)`
- We can only access DOM elements with `prop` other then it gives **`undefined`**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>prop demo</title>
  <style>
    p {
      margin: 20px 0 0;
    }
    b {
      color: blue;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <input id="check1" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <label for="check1">Check me</label>
  <p></p>

  <script>
    $("input").change(function() {
      var $input = $(this);
      $("p").html(
        ".attr( \"checked\" ): <b>" + $input.attr("checked") + "</b><br>" +
        ".prop( \"checked\" ): <b>" + $input.prop("checked") + "</b><br>" +
        ".is( \":checked\" ): <b>" + $input.is(":checked")) + "</b>";
    }).change();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Gary Hole answer is very relevant to solve the problem if the code is written in such way

```
obj.prop("style","border:1px red solid;")
```

Since the prop function return `CSSStyleDeclaration` object, above code will not working properly in some browser(tested with `IE8 with Chrome Frame Plugin` in my case).

Thus changing it into following code

```
obj.prop("style").cssText = "border:1px red solid;"
```

solved the problem.